# How to efficiently sum over subset of last multi-index level in large df?

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, multi-index

[Using python 3.9]

I have a large df with the following stylized structure:

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = [('BLOCK', i, j) for i in ['X', 'Y'] for j in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
data = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['top', 'mid', 'bottom'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

```
top    BLOCK               
mid        X        Y      
bottom     a  b  c  a  b  c
0          1  1  1  1  1  2
```

The original df has many such blocks next to each other, and only the bottom-level labels are repeated.

I would like to sum over a subset of the bottom level, drop the summed columns and replace them with a column that has the sum, like this:

```
top    BLOCK           
mid        X      Y    
bottom     a b+c  a b+c
0          1   2  1   3
```

I can achieve this by going into each block and each middle level, do the summation over the subset of columns and then reindexing and stacking everything up again via concatenation. But I am hoping there is a more efficient way.

I thought maybe
`df.groupby(level=['top', 'mid'], axis='columns')`
in combination with something else was an alternative, maybe by aggregate separately over specific groups, but haven't found a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby method on the bottom level of the multi-index and then sum the subsets of the bottom level you want to aggregate. Then use reorder_levels and swaplevel to move the bottom level to the top, drop it and rename the columns. Finally, use unstack to move the sum column to the right place in the DataFrame.

Here's an example:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level='bottom', axis='columns').sum()
grouped = grouped.reorder_levels([1, 0], axis='columns')
grouped = grouped.swaplevel(0, 1, axis='columns')
grouped = grouped.sum(level=0, axis='columns').rename(columns={0: 'a 
b+c'})
result = grouped.unstack().rename(columns={0: 'a b+c'})
```

Comment: This doesn't run for me.

Comment: And the first line sums over all bottom entries, not just over the subset as needed.

Comment: You need to test your code first to ensure it does indeed work. Not only would this code return incorrect data if it did work, it crashes at the second line (grouped return does not have multi-level columns)